# UITableView data is not reloading when user sends request to server and user switches to another screen and comes back to previous

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

UITableView` data is not reloading when user sends request to server & user switches to another screen and come back to previous, after coming back user gets response from server & according to the response table view is not reloading.

However the array values got refreshed.

```
            NSString *conString=[[[delegate.serverId stringByAppendingString:@"/ven/"] stringByAppendingString:[dict valueForKey:@"Item_Id"]] stringByAppendingString:@"/picture"];
            NSLog(@"Post image in add image url %@",conString);

            NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:conString]];
            [req setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:conString]];
            [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            NSString *boundary = @"0x0hHai1CanHazB0undar135";
            NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
            [req addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
            // [req setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

            NSString *token =delegate.Token;
            NSLog(@"Token %@",token);
            [req setValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];


            NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
            // NSLog(@"Image data in content upload %@",imageData);

            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[dict valueForKey:@"Value"]];
            [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];




            // mimeType

            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"mimeType\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",mimeType] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


            // close form
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            // set request body
            [req setHTTPBody:body];



            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                if (data) {

                    NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
                    if ([responseString isEqualToString:@"The supplied authentication is not authorized to access this resource"]) {
                        //[self checkSessionOfUser];
                        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LogoutNotifyMyTask" object:nil];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
                    NSLog(@"Respnse String Add Image%@",responseString);
                    NSError *error = nil;
                    NSDictionary *json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
                    NSLog(@"Result image %@ %@",json,[dict valueForKeyPath:@"Item_Id"]);
                    if ([json valueForKey:@"url"]) {

           if ([myTaskIdMyTask containsObject:[dict valueForKey:@"Item_Id"]]) 
             {
           int addImageIndex=(int)[myTaskIdMyTask indexOfObject:[dict valueForKeyPath:@"Item_Id"]];

          [updationStatusMyTask replaceObjectAtIndex:addImageIndex withObject:@"Completed"];

                     UITableView*  myTab=(UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:-2];                        
                                [myTab beginUpdates];
                                [myTab reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:addImageIndex inSection:0], nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                                [myTab endUpdates];                              

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                  }
                }
                else
                {

                }

            } ];
```

Comment: Could you provide some code with your server's response handling?

Comment: Posting some code would be really useful. If the values are retrieved in a different controller, are they sent to the table view controller when you perform the segue?

Comment: Is your server code is in viewDidLoad?

Comment: No,Request to server is going from action in uitableview

Answer (score 1):

Call `[tableView reloadData]`after you got your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your request was completed and you stored data in tableView's datasource then just reload your tableview when coming back:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

But if you don't get the data before leaving the view, then this might not work.

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Thanks for reply,But My Problem is this when request go to server if response from server get delay and user go on some other screens and come back to previous one and here user get the response after some time for that request. Values get change according to response  but table not reload data. According to me this is happening because send request to server go in another thread and when user come back table view works as another thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a little bit confused...
What's that??

```
UITableView*  myTab=(UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:-2];
                 myTab.delegate=self;
                 myTab.dataSource=self;
                            [myTab beginUpdates];
                            [myTab reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:addImageIndex inSection:0], nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                            [myTab endUpdates];
```

Listen, I think the best way is to make the ViewController only a simple view controller. Use a model to send request and to organize your tableview data source. Then, when the operation is completed, you have to call your VC with a delegate method to update the table. It is more clean and a bit more smart.

The flow will be like this:

ViewController want to send a request with some params. It will contact the model and the model will do the request. Model will populate an NSArray (or something else) property that will be used by VC for the dataSource. So model completes the request and elaborates datas. Then, when it finished, it will call the VC with the delegate method (for ex `-(void)yourModel: (YourModel *)model successfullyUpdatedDatas;`). So in your delegate method, you will call the `-(void)reloadData` method.

I hope I was clear. Bye and happy new year.